# Choosing specific colors for different levels of column in a data_frame when graphing with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot2` to make several graphs from a large data frame. The graphs are bar graphs showing proportions of two levels of a column in the data-frame, Yes and No. The colors are chosen by default, and  want to make one of the levels either completely transparent, or choose a different color for it.

My code to graph is the following:

```
    ggplot(data=encuestas ,aes(x = colonia,fill = p1))  +
    theme(legend.position="bottom", axis.title.x=element_blank())  +
    geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

I have tried using `geom_bar`, and the colors change successfully, but the chart graphs count instead of proportion when using `geom_bar`.

These are the default colors for the levels:

[image: These are the default colors for the levels that I'd like to change or make one of them translucent:]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That's how `geom_bar` works. Did you read the help file for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scale_fill_manual` to set the colour of the bars, and `ylab` to change the default axis label ('count').

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(vs))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  ylab("Proportion")
```